# UDP client prints received data twice [i.e. received data is appended on itself twice]

Tags: objective-c, sockets, udp

GOAL: I'm making a UDP socket to send and receive data. 
I am testing this on my laptop, so I have a server running on the background that listens to incoming messages and echoing this back.

PROBLEM: I am seeing that the server receives one string, and when it echoes back, the client reads the string 2 times instead of ONE and adds gibberish.How to solve this?

Output from the code is: HelloHello09[btw i als get some questionsmarks that are upside down in front of the 09 and behind it, but I cannot paste it, lolz]

Code:

```
#define BUFLEN 5
#define PORT 12345

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define srvr_IP "127.0.0.1"

void errorSig(char *); 

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
int sockSend = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_in si_other;

char buf[BUFLEN] = "Hello";
char bufrec[BUFLEN]; 

@autoreleasepool {

    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, srvr_IP, &si_other.sin_addr); 
    memset(&si_other.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(si_other.sin_zero));

    int size = sizeof(si_other); 
    sendto(sockSend, buf, BUFLEN, 0,
           (struct sockaddr *)&si_other, size);

    recvfrom(sockSend, bufrec, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&si_other, (unsigned int*)&size); 
    NSString *test = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:bufrec];
    NSLog(@" data is: %@", test); 

    close(sockSend); 
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like `C` to me?!

Comment: What @Nick said. What is all this "@autoreleasepool" and "[NSString alloc]" stuff? At a guess the issue is something to do with the way strings are being NULL terminated (or not), you may well find buf and bufrec are adjacent in memory and if there is no gap between them, and no null terminator, then you are getting both printed out together. It's impossible to tell without more information though, for example what is BUFLEN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just seen that you did in fact define BUFLEN as 5 (sorry I missed that when I wrote my comment above). As I suspected, you have a NULL termination issue. The length of a string in C is one more than the number of characters you want to store, to make room for the NULL terminator indicating the end of the string.

Change your BUFLEN definition to 6 and you should find it works much better.